# Unwanted URL repeating/appended in Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I seem to have a problem with my Google Analytics.

My pages are being shown as 404 errors as the full URL address is being repeated after the foldername.

Example:
My page for cars is:
/cars/

But Google Analytics is showing this page as 
/cars/www.domain.com

There are no filters set that I can see but I don't know how to resolve it.
Is this common?  It is a Wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

You have a link somewhere that starts with www.example.com, but should start with http://www.example.com (or https://www.example.com).

URLs that don't start with a protocol (http://, https:// or just :// to mean "the same protocol this document was requested with") or a / are interpreted to be relative to the current document, e.g. if you are on http://www.example.org/cars/ and you link to "mercedes/", it yields http://www.example.org/cars/mercedes/. This is what happens for you, because you have an incomplete URL somewhere. Look at your document source in your browser and search for www.example.com. You will most likely find something like `href="www.example.com"`. Find the link in your post / template that is responsible, and change it to `href="http://www.example.com"` or `href="https://www.example.com"`, depending on what that host supports.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you might find that Google Analytics is adding your domain name after every URL slug captured and it can make for some messy reporting.

For example, our homepage would return

/nichemarket.co.za

and the blog page would return

/blog/nichemarket.co.za

If your site analytics account returns a similar issue, this is not standard practice and is generally due to a misconfiguration of the view filter.

To fix this issue head over to your Google Analytics account and click the Admin tab in the right-hand menu.

Navigate to view
Select view settings
Scroll down to default page
Remove your domain name from the text box and leave it blank
Click save